# Как в discord.py добавить смайл на сервер?

Tags: python, discord, бот

Я хочу при использовании команды добавлять смайл на сервер

```py
@client.command
async def добавить(ctx):
  with open("check-mark-microsoft") as img:
    img_byte = img.read()
    await ctx.guild.create_custom_emoji(name = ("ok"), image = img_byte)
```

Пока только так...
В чём ошибка?

Если что пишу на [replit](https://replit.com/%7E)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в открытии файла. Вам нужен байт-код, значит в аргументах в `with open()` нужно указать режим `"rb"`.  Как-то так:

```
@bot.command()
async def create_emoji(ctx: commands.Context, filename: str, name: str):
    with open(filename, "rb") as image:
        img_byte = image.read()
    await ctx.guild.create_custom_emoji(name=name, image=img_byte)
```

Чтобы удалить смайл можно воспользоваться `await ctx.guild.delete_custom_emoji(guild id, emoji id)`

```
@bot.command()
async def delete_emoji(ctx: commands.Context, emoji: discord.Emoji):
    await ctx.guild.delete_custom_emoji(ctx.guild.id, emoji.id)
```

Comment: А каким методом можно удалить смайл?

Comment: await ctx.guild.delete_custom_emoji(ctx.guild.id, emoji.id)